# Retrieving data with a resolver in Angular 6 but in the objects the arrays are null. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular6, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1, angular-resolver

I have a path 'user/edit' to edit to current logged in user. I have an tab that i want to edit an array of 'Recipe'-s that every user has. I am getting the data about the user with a resolver. And i am getting all his Recipes. The problem is that every recipe has an array of 'Photo'-s, and this array for every 'Recipe' is null. How i can these data?

This is my Resolver

```
export class UserDetailResolver implements Resolve<User> {
constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router,
private authService: AuthService, private notif: NgxNotificationService ) 
{}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User> {
    return this.userService.getUser(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
            this.notif.sendMessage('Problem retrieving data', 'warning', 'bottom-right');
            this.router.navigate(['/users']);
            return of(null);
        })
    );
}
}
```

user-edit.component:

```
  export class UserEditComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  recipes: Recipe[];
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
     this.user = data['user'];
     });
```

In other section of my app i have no problem to Show all Recipes with their photos, and made a gallery and everything  is fine. May be i should use second resolver to resolve every recipe in the array, but i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, te problem was in the api. i wasn-t including my photos to the reponse. If the admins decide delete the question or lock it.